# fitting t distribution with lighter tails

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, fitting, t-distribution

I am trying to fit a t distribution in R using the fitdistr function in the MASS package as follows

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(9999); sample <- rt(5000, df=50)    
fitdistr(sample, "t")
```

While the procedure works well for location and scale, the degrees of freedom are significantly off when fitting lighter tails. I realize that it uses a nonlinear optimization procedure to minimize the log likelihood and depends on the start value. However, is there something I can do to get a better fit for dof.

Examining the log-likelihood for random start values of df, does not help.

Comment: Why are you dividing the sample by 100?

Comment: Fitting on percentage scale works well. Moerover, its just scaling the location and scale parameters. You may choose not to divide by 100 but that hardly makes much difference to fitting df.

Comment: Several things: I don't know what you mean by "fitting on a percentage scale", but I'm fairly certain you are confused about what that's doing, as I can't see any reasonable motive for this. Second, and very importantly, note that the R functions for a t distribution (`dt`, most importantly) do **not** have a scale parameter. So dividing by 100 is really going to mess up your estimation: there's no t distribution (not rescaled) that looks like a $t_{50} / 100$! Finally, fitting the degrees of freedom will be pretty difficult. Expect plenty of error in that estimate (even after not rescaling).

Comment: Of course I have to rescale the location and scale back, but if it causes confusion, I will remove the scaling by 100. Do you have a strategy to fit lighter tails with t distribution

Comment: hmm, sorry, I just used `fitdistr` and see that apparently it *does* fit 's', a scaling parameter. So you are correct that rescaling will be okay. That being said, it's still *really* hard to estimate the degrees of freedom; the difference between a $t_{25}$ and $t_{50}$ is very minimal! So I wouldn't expect to do much better than what you have done. Also, I doubt the likelihood is multimodal, so different starting values are unlikely to give results that differ more than numeric error.